# How do i make Google Sheets ignore conditional formatting when I am setting the colour of the cell using GAS?

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I have a script that paints the cell red and also puts some text inside of a cell if it is merged:

```
function myFun() {
  let ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  let range = ss.getDataRange();
  let activeRange = ss.getRange("A1:AH60");
  Logger.log(activeRange);
  let mergedRanges = activeRange.getMergedRanges();
  Logger.log(mergedRanges);
  Logger.log(range);

  mergedRanges.forEach(function(range) {
    range.setValue("my value");
    range.setBackground("red");
  });

  let timestamp = ss.getRange("A1");
  timestamp.setValue("script successfully ran " + new Date()); 

}
```

However, I have conditional formatting that I need in the google sheets that paint the cell green if it is not blank. Can I somehow assign higher priority to the colour set by script over the colour set by conditional formatting in Google Sheets not having to change anything in conditional formatting?

I am confused as I don't really know what I can try to solve this.

Comment: Is it possible to do what you want manually in the user interface?

Comment: nope, the colour stays the same if i try to paint the cell that is "affected" by conditional formatting

Comment: I think clearing the format for that cell and then applying your format is the way to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### **Recommended:**

Conditional formatting overwrites the changes made by App Script. To achieve both of your conditions, the script below will set the background to green if the cell is not blank, red if the cells are merged and white if the cell is blank.

```
function myFun(){
  let ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  let activeRange = ss.getRange("A1:AH60");
  let val = activeRange.getValues();
  let mergedRanges = activeRange.getMergedRanges();

  val.forEach((x,i) => 
    x.forEach((y,j) => {
      if(y != "") // check if the cell is not empty and it will change the value to green
        ss.getRange(i+1,j+1).setBackground("green");
      else // if the cell is blank it will change the color to white
        ss.getRange(i+1,j+1).setBackground("white");
    })
  );

  mergedRanges.forEach(function(range) {
    range.setValue("my value");
    range.setBackground("red");
  });

  let timestamp = ss.getRange("A1");
  timestamp.setValue("script successfully ran " + new Date()); 

}
```

**Sample Output:**

[image]

**Reference:**

- [forEach](https://spreadsheet.dev/foreach-loop-in-apps-script)

Comment: Thank for the suggested solution! Since I am new to coding, could you please elaborate on what x, i, y, j are in your code? I think they are parameters that function accepts and you can assign any name you want to those parameters, right? But at this point I don't really understand which values are passed to (x,i) and (y,j). Values of the cell in the selected range (A1:AH60)?

Comment: I would've upvote your answer, but don't have enough rep to do that sorry

Comment: @Spanner yes x,i,y,j are just parameters you can assign any names to call it. But to be clear x and y are the values and i and j are indexes. We use nested forEach to get the exact value of the cells (A1:AH60) and check if it is empty or not.